# How do I make the map CONTAINER be allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++11

Basically I have this map container :

```
map <int, double> r_t_plus_1;
```

I know that r_t_plus_1 is on the stack, and its elements go into dynamic allocation.
I want to know whether I can get the container on heap, through an allocator property or is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Why would you need it in the heap? You can pass your `map` object wherever you want without copying by using move semantics or references

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I have the container in a function and want to use it in main. So I can't return the reference of it if it's local. I also want to avoid copying.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806165/why-is-stdstring-stdmap-not-encouraged-to-be-created-on-the-heap

Comment: In C++11 an implementation is allowed to elide copies (and moves, which are a kind of copy) in ways that change the observable behaviour of the program. "I also want to avoid copying" so do the designers of the language

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use `new` or `make_unique()` to allocate it on the heap, and store it in a smart pointer:

```
auto r_t_plus_1 = std::make_unique<std::map<int, double>>();
```

You could also use make_shared if you want a shared pointer.

Comment: This should almost never be necessary though.